# Python - Passing email body as variable into SendEmail function

Tags: python, smtp

I am using a workflow automation program called Alteryx. It has its own "Send Email" tool but it is inherently limited to 10mb attachments and I have a number of daily/weekly reports that are larger than that. I am trying to design a short example workflow that can intake an array of variables that represent different parts of an email. I have each piece working except for the email body. I am trying to write it in a way so that anything can be input as the body string variable, but it seems like single quotes, double quotes, and slashes break that variable though the email still sends just with an empty body.

Is there a way I can encode the entire variable to get python to ignore every escape character in the input string? Should I build in some processing before the Python step that replaces ' with ''' etc?

```
# List all non-standard packages to be imported by your 
# script here (only missing packages will be installed)
from ayx import Package
#Package.installPackages(['pandas','numpy'])

from ayx import Alteryx

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

pyArray = Alteryx.read("#1")
body = pyArray["pymailBody"][0]

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = pyArray["pymailFrom"][0]
msg['To'] = pyArray["pymailTo"][0]
msg['CC'] = pyArray["pymailCC"][0]
msg['BCC'] = pyArray["pymailBCC"][0]
msg['Subject'] = pyArray["pymailSubject"][0]
msg['Body'] = body.encode('unicode_escape')
attachmentName = pyArray["pymailAttachmentName"][0]
attachmentPath = pyArray["pymailAttachmentPath"][0]

part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(attachmentPath, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachmentName)

msg.attach(part)

with smtplib.SMTP("mail.company.com", 25) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: The body of an e-mail isn't a *header*.  So there's a good chance that the Alteryx dependency has nothing to do with the problem and could be removed from the example code.

Comment: What is returned if you print `pyArray["pymailBody"]`? My suspicion is that either the issue is occurring upstream or that is a string so `pyArray["pymailBody"][0]` would be capturing just the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier (except, curiously, the use of `smtplib.send_message`). The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. My suspicion is that simply upgrading to the modern version of the library should solve your conundrum.

Most acutely, the old `email.message.Message` or its `MIMEMultipart` etc brethren did not usefully have `msg['Body']` for setting the body of the message; but overall, you want to move away from using those legacy APIs.

Reading more than I like between the lines, I'm guessing your code should be refactored to something like

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

from ayx import Alteryx  # , Package was never used


pyArray = Alteryx.read("#1")

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = pyArray["pymailFrom"][0]
msg['To'] = pyArray["pymailTo"][0]
msg['CC'] = pyArray["pymailCC"][0]
msg['BCC'] = pyArray["pymailBCC"][0]
msg['Subject'] = pyArray["pymailSubject"][0]

msg.set_content(pyArray["pymailBody"][0])  # no encoding here, just pass in the Unicode text

with open(pyArray["pymailAttachmentPath"][0], "rb") as payload:
    msg.add_attachment(
        payload.read(),
        maintype='application', subtype='octet-stream',
        filename=pyArray["pymailAttachmentName"][0])

with smtplib.SMTP("mail.company.com", 25) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.send_message(msg)
```

(If you really wanted to add an explicit `Content-Disposition:` it could be done, of course; but the default disposition handling should be fine for an `application/octet-stream` attachment.)

It is unfortunate that there are enough old examples of how to send email in Python to populate several of Saturn's rings, but your first stop should be the official Python documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html is an excellent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I got my code to work by importing MIMEText and moving the body variable down into

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(pyArray["pymailBody"][0]))
```

@tripleee's answer is an overall upgrade over what I'd cobbled together, so I'll actually be moving forward with that. Thank you, @tripleee!

```
from ayx import Package
from ayx import Alteryx
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders

pyArray = Alteryx.read("#1")

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = pyArray["pymailFrom"][0]
msg['To'] = pyArray["pymailTo"][0]
msg['CC'] = pyArray["pymailCC"][0]
msg['BCC'] = pyArray["pymailBCC"][0]
msg['Subject'] = pyArray["pymailSubject"][0]
attachmentName = pyArray["pymailAttachmentName"][0]
attachmentPath = pyArray["pymailAttachmentPath"][0]

part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(attachmentPath, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachmentName)

msg.attach(MIMEText(pyArray["pymailBody"][0]))
msg.attach(part)

with smtplib.SMTP("mail.company.com", 25) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: That's nice, but again, you really want to move away from these legacy APIs. They will still be around, but they are a lot clunkier and more brittle than the modern `EmailMessage` API.